# Updating UIView by pressing button

Tags: swift, uiview, viewcontroller, reload

I have little problem with my app. On main ViewController i have embbed Container View with objective-C chart.

[image]

I have 2 buttons and always when i press it i need update this UIView. Everything like setNeedsDisplay() not working.

But when i go to another ViewController and going back, my chart is updated.

Here is my main controller:

[image]

By buttons i go to previous year and data not updated.
But going to Another ViewController and:

[image]

Booom data updated. Im trying methods like: IBAction when button is pressed call function setNeedsDisplay() for self or view.

Thanks for your time! PS: Its not table, its CONTAINER VIEW.

Comment: is objective-c chart a library/cocoapod, I couldn't find it? Best way to give you an answer is to see code on how the container view is implemented.

Comment: Please post some of the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my project tree:

[TREE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UC28.png)

and i have container view to embbed this:

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whqAo.png)

So i just need refresh UIViewController when i press button. Doesnt have any conection with objective-c to swift code (just one string array).